# CoreGraphics, Memory Deallocation, Return Values

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, core-graphics

I seem to always have a lot of trouble with managing memory with CoreGraphics when I'm returning from a method. Take the situation below:

```
- (id) init
{
    CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    //mutable path gets loaded with some hard data

    return [self initWithMutablePath:mutablePath];
}

- (id) initWithMutablePath:(CGMutablePathRef)mutablePath
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) 
    {
        _mutablePath = (CGMutablePathRef) CGPathRetain(mutablePath);
    }

    return self;  
}
```

Am getting this message from instruments:

```
Potential leak of an object allocated on line 38 and stored into 'mutablePath'
```

I do want the initWithMutablePath:(CGMutablePathRef)mutablePath initializer to retain mutablePath, because it might be called from else where where it will be needed. Yet, I also want to the init method to be able to pass mutablePath to it without incident. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: CGPathRetain may be the reason.. CGPathCreateMutable gives you a retained state and why use CGPathRetain again?

Comment: @LithuThiruvathira  - Yeah I think it is, but that initializer also needs to be called from else where so I kind of need to keep it that way.

Comment: make     CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
in an if loop if(mutablepath) and then add it in the initWithMutablePath: method  removing tht from the init method

Comment: thanks @LithuThiruvathira, you know I just ended up getting rid of one of the initializers and it works fine now. what I was trying to do seemed not possible unless wanted to make it messy. appreciate your comments though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as what I'm trying to do is impossible, so I ended up just getting rid of initWithMutablePath (this was the constructor for a base class) and I ended up not implementing a constructor in the base class. I have the children class that inherit off it implement the initializer and load the path.